# JavaFX repeated @FXML tags workaround

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am curently trying JavaFX for a school project. While this is not really a problem for me, it sometimes irritates  me to put the @FXML tag always before each declaration, like this:

```
@FXML ListView accountsList;
@FXML ListView videosList;
@FXML ListView quizItems;
@FXML Label account_name;
@FXML Label account_quiz;
@FXML Label video_title;
@FXML Label video_desc;
@FXML Label item_a;
@FXML Label item_b;
@FXML Label item_c;
@FXML Label item_question;
```

Why can't I do it like this?

```
@FXML Label lbl1, lbl2, lbl3; // only lbl3 works, but the others not
// (lbl1, lbl2 is not detected in JavaFX SceneBuilder)
```

... or what is the correct method of doing it? Thanks and pardon my english grammar. :)

Comment: You could use [JRubyFX](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx/wiki/Getting-Started), it has it's own FXML loader that gets rid of the need for @FXML controller tags entirely (note, it works on Ruby rather than Java).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that sometime... but for the meantime I shall master JavaFX first. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in javafx if you create any control(label,buton etc) in fxml file you need to put @FXML before use it..because @FXML show that the variable initalise at fxml....

one better way that to not write this.you already use scene builder.
now follow this steps...

1. open view-> show sample controller skeleton
2. now copy all inital functions and variables values and paste them into your controller file.

[image]

[image]

it reduce your time