# How to map javafx2.0 .fxml UI with my program?

Tags: javafx

I have designed a UI for my program using javafx scene builder. Now I don't know how to map this with the functionality of my program as I am new to javafx. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [skeleton code of controller file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992599/javafx-repeated-fxml-tags-workaround/). this will provide you FX code of your xml now copy this code and paste into your controller file.